# How to get my iPhone readable

Tags: ios

I have hit various unknown thing

My iPhone is now very dark and unreadable.

How do I get it reset to normal

I suspect if I could change brightness that might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't see the screen, try asking Siri. Hold the side button and say ‘increase the brightness’.

Answer (score 0):

You can take your phone into a very dark room and then you may be able to read it. I had same problem and this worked for me.